# Why is the menu I created not working with a new Intent

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android development.

I created a MenuItem to start a new activity (SettingsActivity) when clicked. I have no errors and everything is working fine except that when I click the created menu, it does not do anything.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.visualizer_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

 public boolean onOptionSelected(MenuItem item){
        int itemThatWasClicked = item.getItemId();

        if (itemThatWasClicked == R.id.action_settings){
            Intent settingsActivityIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);// using explicity intent to open new activity
            startActivity(settingsActivityIntent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I have tried adding a Toast in `onOptionSelected()`, it didn't work. the menu is not just responding

I have the following code in my SettingsActivity.java for now

```
package android.example.com.visualizerpreferences;

import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null){
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Below is my visualizer_menu.xml in my menu resource file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your

```java
public boolean onOptionSelected(MenuItem item){
```

to

```java
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Menu item create :

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Click listeners :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.new_game:
        newGame();
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        showHelp();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```